# Logic Apps custom connector - unable to upload the Postman collection

Tags: azure, postman, azure-logic-apps, postman-collection

I'm trying to create a Logic Apps custom connector based on a Postman collection.
When I'm on the stage to provide the Postman collection in the custom connector blade in the Azure portal, I can't upload the collection because nothing is provided in the screen for that as shown in the screenshot : 
[image: ScreeShot]

Comment: Did you want through the docs for Custom Connector for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-overview) and [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-build-web-api-app-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a bug that recently appeared in this experience. We are rolling out the fix in a few hours. Apologies for the inconvenience. Feel free to ping me for updates if you don’t see it resolved today. Logicappsemail at Microsoft dot com